# Show organization chart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory

I need to show the organization chart of employee and employer. How can I do this using Active Directory and SharePoint 2013?

Is there a way to do it in javascript to get a JSON data?

Comment: Do you want to implement it through JavaScript only or out of the box option will do?

Comment: Did you take a look at the out-of-the box Option insides the mysites?

Comment: actually i need both of them , inside mysiteand   using OTB , and in top level site to show all groups and employer that's why i thought about Json data , so I can show the data in chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your needs. So your question is quite general.

You are able to reuse the control from SharePoint OOB that is being used in the My Sites. But if you want to get kind of JSON data out of the Active Directory you need to provide a custom solution.

Either you implement a CustomControl that is accessing your Active Directory with [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145037%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or you provide a web service that connects to the AD and returns the data in a JSON format.

When you want to show your data in a visual control like a chart you won't achieve that with using the OOB features of SharePoint. You have to develop your own custom solution.